# How to create a Sitecore Module WDP packge **WITH** Sitecore items?

Tags: azure, powershell-extensions, packages

I was following the official documentation on the subject here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/20/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html and realized that **it looks like we can't add Sitecore Items to the generated WDP package**.

Am I missing something or it's really that?

Do you guys know how to create a WDP package with items on it?

Comment: the initial WDP will be generated with the use of Sitecore package right.? So you can have your items in the Sitecore package and convert that to WDP. Refer "Generating an Initial WDP" section in the above link which you shared.

Comment: Using "ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path <string> -Destination <string>" lets you convert a .zip sitecore package to a wdp package. 

But having serialized Items within the initial .zip package don't automatically publish to core and master as expected during the msdeployed operation.

Feels like they need dacpac or sql data maybe ..? I also got to deploy items within the solution without being recognized as items, and not converted into sitecore items nor published. They just sits in the solution as is(xml).